# Prove that the set $U_1 =\{(123),(124),.....,(12n)\}$ generates $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Here $A_n$ = the alternating group on n symbols.

We are given a hint:

$(abc) = (1ca)(1ab)$

$(1ab)=(1b2)(12a)(12b)$

$(1b2)=(12b)^2$

I am unsure where to start. Can someone give me a jump start?

Answer (score 1):

I think we need $n \geq 3$. Note that $\langle U_1 \rangle \leq A_n$.

> Recall that $A_n$ consists of all permutations which can be written as an even product of transpositions

So, you can see that $A_n$ is generated by the set of all products of two distinct 2-cycles. Each product $\sigma$ of two 2-cycles has one of two forms.

$$\sigma = (ab)(cd) = (acb)(acd) \in \langle U_1 \rangle,$$

$$\sigma = (ab)(ac) = (acb) \in \langle U_1 \rangle.$$

So, $A_n \leq \langle U_1 \rangle$. We got the conclusion.